# Blob returns invalid pdf file

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, webapi

I am using ASP.NET core and angular  to build a web application . I am returning File from one of the actions of a controller

```
return Ok(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.File(await GetFileCOntents(args),"application/pdf"));
```

and I am reading the output contents in typescript as follows

```
 this.myService.getPDFFile(requestData)
    .subscribe(data => this.downloadFile(data))

 private downloadFile(data: any) {
       const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        saveAs(blob, 'result.pdf');
  }
```

When i inspect the data contents I can see the bytes

```
{
  "fileContents": "JVBERi0xLjQNCiWio4+TDQo0IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UaXRsZSA8RkVGRj4gL0F1dGhvciA8RkVGRj4gL1N1YmplY3QgPEZFRkY+IC9LZXl3b3JkcyA8RkVGRj4gL0NyZWF0b3IgPEZFRkY+IC9Qcm9kdWNlciA8RkVGRjAwNDQwMDY1MDA3NjAwNjUwMDZDMDA2RjAwNzAwMDY1MDA3MjAwMjAwMDQ1MDA3ODAwNzAwMDcyMDA2NTAwNzMwMDczMDAyMDAwNDkwMDZFMDA2MzA..
"contentType": "application/pdf",
  "fileDownloadName": "",
  "lastModified": null,
  "entityTag": null,
  "enableRangeProcessing": false
}
```

However when I save and open the pdf file. It says invalid pdf file. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @KJ How do I inspect the downloaded pdf file for any errors?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding here. The file is getting saved as pdf

Comment: should I copy the contents manually and save it as pdf ?

Comment: thank you it worked but no my pdf is blank

Comment: so how do i get the data back? where do i change?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller has to return:

```cs
   return File(fileResult.File, fileResult.FileMime, fileResult.FileName);
```

This is code of one of my projects. It gets file, creates hidden `<a></a>` with target `_blank` and clicks the anchor to open document in next tab.

```
  private downloadFile(request: ContractDocument): void {
    this.documentService.download(request.id).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        if (!data) {
          return;
        }
        let downloadedFile: Blob;
        let a: HTMLAnchorElement;
        switch (data.type) {
          default:
            break;
          case HttpEventType.Response:
            this.isDownloading = false;
            downloadedFile = new Blob([data.body!], {
              type: data.body!.type,
            });
            a = document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.download = request!.fileName!;
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(downloadedFile);
            a.target = '_blank';
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            break;
        }
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.showError(error);
        this.isDownloading = false;
      },
    });
```